# Spring Boot 2.x doesn't load application.properties in JUnit test

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

Consider the following code:

```
@Profile("prod")
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyService.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class TestMyService {

    @Autowired
    MyService myService;
```

`MyService` has:

```
@Value("${my.service.api.key}")
protected String apiKey;
```

The problem is that when running some test under `TestMySrevice` the field `apiKey` doesn't get injected.

I tried doing the following

```
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application.properties")
```

but it didn't help

How to fix that?

Comment: What's your version of Spring Boot?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki, Spring Boot 2.x